# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection-EF

Tags: entity-framework, rawsql

I am using EF's DBContext to execute the stored proc. Here is the function

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomerInfoforSearch(string bfcSalesRecipientId, string companyName, string contactName, string phoneNumber, string emailId, string ageroProviderNumber)
{
    var bfcSalesRecipientIdParam = new SqlParameter("@saleRecipientId", bfcSalesRecipientId);
    var companyNameParam = new SqlParameter("@companyName", companyName);
    var contactNameParam = new SqlParameter("@contactName", contactName);
    var phoneNumberParam = new SqlParameter("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    var emailIdParam = new SqlParameter("@emailId", emailId);
    var ageroProviderNumParam = new SqlParameter("@ageroProviderNumber", ageroProviderNumber);

    object[] sqlParams = new object[] { bfcSalesRecipientIdParam, companyNameParam, contactNameParam, phoneNumberParam, emailIdParam, ageroProviderNumParam };
    var result = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("dbo.Customer_SearchContact {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", bfcSalesRecipientIdParam, companyNameParam, contactNameParam, phoneNumberParam, emailIdParam, ageroProviderNumParam).ToList();
   return result;
}
```

But this throws the following error:

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Comment: Are you getting this error while debugging by any chance?

Comment: yes! It does. And I tried to quick watch what happens, the same thing happens. Also the logs show the same errors

Comment: You are just seeing the result of deferred execution. When you debug it, the results are executed, then when the app runs on, it tries to run it again. Don't do that!

Comment: IF I don't debug I get this error:    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MVC.EntityFramework.Customer'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.  But I have ovverriden the "ID" attribute with bfcSaleRecipientId attribute as the column name